# How do you interpret a network prefix derived from an irregular subnet mask?

Tags: networking, ip, mask, subnet

If an internal IP is 192.168.1.5 and the subnet mask is 255.210.255.0, and they are bitwise ANDed:

1100 0000. 1010 1000. 0000 0001. 0000 0101

1111 1111. 1101 0010. 1111 1111. 0000 0000

1100 0000. 1000 0000. 0000 0001. 0000 0000

The result is 192.128.1.0. How can my IP be allowed on the subnet if it is a 192.168.* .* number?

P.S. I know that these are rarely used in practice.

Comment: "_How do you interpret a network prefix derived from an irregular subnet mask?_" You don't because it is not a prefix (a CIDR term that requires masks with consecutive ones bits). Non-consecutive network masks have been deprecated for many years (_[RFC 1878, Variable Length Subnet Table For IPv4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1878)_, December 1995).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a non-consecutive network mask, the possible IP addresses are no simple range but multiple non-consecutive ranges. In your case, any 2nd octet bitwise ANDed with %‭11010010‬ equaling (%‭10101000‬ AND %‭11010010‬) is allowed.

Effectively, the network `192.128.1.0/255.210.255.0` consists of the ranges

```
192.128.1.0(network address) - 192.128.1.255
192.129.1.0 - 192.129.1.255
192.132.1.0 - 192.132.1.255
192.133.1.0 - 192.133.1.255
192.136.1.0 - 192.136.1.255
192.137.1.0 - 192.137.1.255
192.140.1.0 - 192.140.1.255
192.141.1.0 - 192.141.1.255
192.160.1.0 - 192.160.1.255
192.161.1.0 - 192.161.1.255
192.164.1.0 - 192.164.1.255
192.165.1.0 - 192.165.1.255
192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.255 (containing 192.168.1.5)
192.169.1.0 - 192.169.1.255
192.172.1.0 - 192.172.1.255
192.173.1.0 - (broadcast)192.173.1.255
```

While this poses no problem for a machine, it's very weird for a human - a good reason to not use it.

Answer (score 0):

The 192.128.1.0 is the network address. Your SUBNET MASK just tells your workstation WHICH subnet it's on, in relation to the whole network. I ran this though a handy online tool that I use to configure Cisco routers here at work, and your 192.168.*.* is well within your network.

[image]

Here's the link to the tool:

https://www.adminsub.net/ipv4-subnet-calculator

Take a look at the calculation descriptions following the result. It will tell you how it calculated the results your given. Yours wouldn't be considered a consecutive (standard) subnet however.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I noticed that as well, and thought the same thing... but realized that the Netmask shown is not for a subnet, but rather the entire network (as though there were no subnets). Not sure why they provide that, but there it is.

Comment: The netmask *defines* the subnet. With nodes supporting this, you can subnet a network using *any* bits from the prefix, not just the last ones (e.g. instead of 172.16.0.0/16 -> 172.16.0.0/17 & 172.16.128.0/17 you'd get 172.16.0.0/255.255.239.0 & 172.16.16.0/255.255.239.0).